# Hiding the Material card on user selection not working

Tags: angular, dynamic

I am creating a launchpad kind of application where the material card will be loaded on user selection. 
In order to handle this dynamically, I am trying to hide the element from TS class but change is not reflecting on the browser. redering of the Cards is happening based on rules to need to make it dynamic.  In order to make it work I am trying with a simpler scenario of one card: 
Card code is like below:

```
    <mat-card class="launchpad-tiles"
  [class.mat-elevation-z8]="true"
  (click)="onCardClick($event)"
  matRipple
  [matRippleCentered]="true"
  [fxHide]="preg" #tiles>
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="patient-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Patient Registration</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>Create new patient</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card class="launchpad-tiles"
```

I have used viewchild directive to get the reference and then setting the attribute in hook AfterViewInit. Change of attribute is not reflecting on the browser. Not sure if I am using the correct hook method.

```
@ViewChild(MatCard, { read: ElementRef, static: false }) lpadTiles: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.lpadTiles.nativeElement.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
}
```

I have also tried to set Flex-Layout attribute FX-HIDE to True but that also didn't work.

I am working on angular for just one month so I might be missing something basic. Please let me know if there is a better way to handle this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I believe this should work for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove somthing from dom, you can use *ngIf structrual directive in angular Like.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition">data</ng-container>
```

when your condition will be true data will be visible and when it will be false it will not be shown. Other thing you can use like this

```
<div [hidden]="true/false"> data</div>
```

it will work same but will not remove element from dom.